# How can I compare value from multiple textboxes

Tags: vb.net

How can i compare decimal value in textboxes in panel1 vs decimal value in textboxes if value in textboxes in panel1 are in tolerantion fields which are in textboxes min_tolerance and max_tolerance.

```
Private Sub FINAL_KONTROLA(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim EmptyTextBoxFound As Boolean = False 'Boolean flag for empty textbox 
    Dim EmptyTextBoxName As String = ""
    Dim max_x As String = max_tolerance.Text
    Dim min_x As String = min_tolerance.Text
    For Each ctl As Control In Panel1.Controls

        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox AndAlso ctl.Visible AndAlso ctl.Text >= max_x AndAlso ctl.Text <= min_x Then
            EmptyTextBoxName = ctl.Name
            EmptyTextBoxFound = True
            ctl.Select()
            ctl.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
            Exit For
            If EmptyTextBoxFound = True Then
                ctl.BackColor = Color.Red
                '.. do whatever you have do
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't actually described what is going wrong when you try this, but I'd suggest that since they're all strings, in order to make a numeric comparison you'd have to cast all the values to decimals first, and then compare them. A string comparison likely won't do what you want.

Comment: And how can i convert all textboxes in panel1 to decimal value?

Comment: like I said, you do it by **casting** them. Did you think to google it?? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/how-to-convert-an-object-to-another-type or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/conversions-between-strings-and-other-types#conversion-of-strings-to-numbers or many others you can easily find by searching based on the information I gave you above.

Comment: I have a one question, how can I call next form after secessfully check everything textboxes? After check everything textboxes if is in tolleration field <max >min

Comment: That sounds like a topic for a new question. The comments section of an existing question are not for asking about or discussing new features. The answer will depend a bit on if you are using ASP.NET WebForms or Windows Forms (it's bit unclear from your code). Please ask a new question about it, and make it clear in your question exactly what the circumstances are, and what research / code attempts you have made so far (after all, it should not be hard to google that topic really!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, thank you

```
 Private Sub FINAL_KONTROLA(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim EmptyTextBoxFound As Boolean = False 'Boolean flag for empty textbox 
    Dim EmptyTextBoxName As String = ""
    Dim max_x As Double = max_tolerance.Text
    Dim min_x As Double = min_tolerance.Text

    For Each ctl As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox AndAlso ctl.Visible Then
            Dim v1 As Double = ctl.Text
            If v1 >= max_x OrElse v1 <= min_x Then

                EmptyTextBoxName = ctl.Name
                EmptyTextBoxFound = True
                ctl.Select()
                ctl.Text = ""
                ctl.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
                MsgBox("Vyznačený záznam neodpovída tolerančnímu poli",, "Chyba")
                Exit For
                If EmptyTextBoxFound = True Then
                    ctl.BackColor = Color.Red
                    '.. do whatever you have do
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```